# Error when trying to getting table cell value

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, html-table

I'm trying to create an array of IP address and port number from [this website](http://www.freeproxylists.net/?s=pr).
but the problem is I get a error

> TypeError: table.rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName(...)[0] is undefined

This is my code:

```
var table = document.getElementsByClassName('DataGrid')[0];
var n = table.rows.length;
console.log(n);
var list="";

for(var i=1;i<n;i++){

    //var ip = table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML;
    var port = table.rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML; // error here
    //list+="{"+ip+","+port+"}";

}
```

first cell value pattern is like below.

```
<td><script type="text/javascript">IPDecode("")</script><a href="http://www.freeproxylists.net/1.179.183.85.html">1.179.183.85</a></td>
```

so I think I'm doing it right. Am I doing some silly mistake ?

Note: I debug and already found there are some rows which doesn't have a second cells, but problem is I get a error. I don't get at least one output expect length. See the image:

[image]

Comment: Adding some debug code to that loop, it looks like all is well until the script hits an ad banner row -- here, of course, the elements don't match what you're looking for (there's an `iframe` containing an ad, instead). I'd suggest checking the `length` of that `getElementsByTagName()` call, and if it's not what you expect, `continue` on to the next row.

Comment: @PaulRoub problem is i don't get at least one output .see the image

Comment: Yes you do. You get "53", the row count. Nothing else in your script *would* output anything. I added something like `console.log(table.rows[i].cells[0])` inside the loop to see what was happening.

Comment: @PaulRoub oops i can't imaging why i didn't see it.tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some rows of this table contain adds and do not follow the row(cell(a)) structure you're trying to get. Whenever you get the result of a `get...By...` you should check if it is null, and if it is just skip over the loop with `continue`.